# db2 - already created table still undefined name

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2, ibm-data-studio

Ok, I'm gonna explain the environment so you can understand my problem.

1. I'm using IBM Data Studio to connect and edit my DB2 database which
   is named `[dgsmdb]`
2. I connect to the database using the username: `dgsmadm` & password: `password`
3. I created a schema named: `[LOGICGATES]`
4. Inside the schema, I have three tables which one is named: `[GATEDETAILS]`

Now, when I invoke the GATEDETAILS table inside the LOGICGATES schema using my stored procedure which looks like this:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT gatename FROM LOGICGATES.GATEDETAILS;
```

I'm encountering a problem which says: `["LOGICGATES.GATEDETAILS" is an undefined name. SQLERROR=42704]`, in which I know that it practically says (in my own understanding) that the table `GATEDETAILS` is not present in the database. This is really bugging me because it is clear to me that I created the `GATEDETAILS` table in the `LOGICGATES` schema successfully. I've been checking this for hours and I still can't find my mistake. I admit that I'm not that good and there is some mistake that I'm somewhat overlooking so I would like to ask for help with this. Whoever out there who can correct my mistake, you're my last hope, I really need this.

Comment: Check and provide the select privilage (and other privilages also if necessary) on this table for your working user/schema `dgsmadm`.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, and I've done what you said, but I'm still suffering from the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

How did you create your table? Did you put the schema before the table?

```
create table LOGICGATES.GATEDETAILS (col1 type, ...)
```

Or you just create the schema and then the tables

```
create schema LOGICGATES;
create table GATEDETAILS (col1 type, ...)
```

If you created the tables in like this second way, your table will be named dgsmadm.GATEDETAILS because of the implicit schema.

Take a look at the catalog

```
select tabschema, tabname from syscat.tables where tabschema not like 'SYS%'
```

Comment: thank you sir, I got an idea with what you said and thankfully I successfully solved the problem with your help